# Unable to understand why a single line in my program is affecting the overall output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program in python that reads a file and uses the information for a certain purpose. However, my first target is to count the number of lines in my text file.

My initial program looked like this :

```
fhand = open("date_to_day.txt",)
n=0
date = input("Enter the day in this format 08-Jan-21 (date-month-year): ")
text = fhand.read()
for line in fhand:
    n=n+1
print("The number of lines : ",n)
```

and the output came out to be :

```
Enter the day in this format 08-Jan-21 (date-month-year): 23-Oct-21
The number of lines :  0
```

The output should be 365 lines but I do not know why is it zero.

However, when I change the code removing a line everything works out to be fine and the number of lines in the output is 365.:

```
fhand = open("date_to_day.txt",)
n=0
date = input("Enter the day in this format 08-Jan-21 (date-month-year): ")
#text = fhand.read()
for line in fhand:
    n=n+1
print("The number of lines : ",n)
```

My new output :

```
Enter the day in this format 08-Jan-21 (date-month-year): 23-Oct-21
The number of lines :  365
```

My text file looks :

```
01-Jan-21   -   Friday
02-Jan-21   -   Saturday
03-Jan-21   -   Sunday
04-Jan-21   -   Monday
```

The list continues by listing all the dates in the year.

Comment: It's because the entire contents of the file were read by *text = fhand.read()* resulting in the input stream being at EOF. Thus your loop *for line in hand* never iterates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `fhand.read()` python reads the contents of the file into memory and you are left at the end of the file with no more rows to count. If you would re-open the file again after you do `read()`, you should then be able to count the lines as you do.

Comment: How should I reopen the file again ?

Comment: `open("date_to_day.txt",)`. This operation opens the file, then you read it.

Comment: Rather than close and re-open the file, it's easier to reset the position back to the beginning with `fhand.seek(0)`, then it can be read again.